# Prototype for C function returning array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, return, prototype

So, I am trying to create a nicely readable `C` function prototype, which returns me an array of strings (ie `char*`). The closest I could came up with is something like:

```
const char * const *entrypoints()
{
    static const char* arrays[] = {"test123", "test2"};
    return arrays;
}
```

however, I don't like the two `*`s in the declaration, it looks scary :) ... But I did not find a way to emphasize the fact that the function is returning an array of strings ... Using the [] in the function declaration leads to funny compile errors (such as 'entrypoints' declared as function returning an array for `const char* (entrypoints() [])` or expected unqualified-id before '[' token for `const char[]* entrypoints()` or `const char*[] entrypoints()` ... yes, the compiler is right in both cases), and google seems to have no answer for this... so here I am.

Is there a way to declare a function prototype *in a nicely readable manner* (this will go in a public API) that will return an array of C strings. Not C++. **C**. Plain old C. If not, I will have to stick to the two star approach ... ie. `char **`. Not that this is something (obscurely) awkward, but I would like to emphasize that the function returns an array of strings. C like strings :)

Comment: You cannot return array types in C (*"A function declarator shall not specify a return type that is a function type or an array type"*), so it's definitely double star time.

Comment: How do you expect the caller to know how many strings there are in the array? You need either a sentinel, or a count.

Comment: @unwind Great question! I think I'll have to think about it ... the sentinel feels more friendly :)

Comment: @unwind You can return a `pointer to array of N pointers to const char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't like the two `*`s in the declaration

I feel sorry for you, but that's how you declare a return type of "array-of-pointers". The array decays into a pointer to its first element, so this declaration is the only way you can accomplish what's needed.

What you can do instead is return a **pointer to the array** of strings:

```
const char *(*fn())[2]
{
    static const char *arr[2] = {
        "foo",
        "bar"
    };
    return &arr;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what function the `static` keyword serves here?I only know it keeps the value of a variable alive between function calls if used before variables.What does it do here?And if it's no bother,tell me what exactly the `const` qualifier does here.

Comment: The problem is that I don't really know how many elements the array has, as pointed out above by @unwind I will need to have a sentinel element, indicating the last element.

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture `static` avoids UB (if the array was automatic and not static, you couldn't return it). `const` is for specifying that the characters of the strings are read-only (which they are since we have string *literals* here.)

Comment: @fritzone Then you have to bee a two-star programmer this time, sorry.

Comment: @H2CO3 That means no other string literals can be placed on that array once they are initialized with the original literals eh?

Comment: @H2CO3 Just like `const` qualifed integer constants?

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture No. That means that you can't write `"string literal"[0] = 'a';`.

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture But read up on the `const` keyword, it's much more complex than to be exlpained in a comment.

Comment: @H2CO3 two stars are better than no stars :D

Comment: @H2CO3 That means we can't change the contents of those string literals right?

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture Yes, it does.

Comment: @H2CO3 Can I feed on you when you dehydrate and collapse while in a desert?

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture Why not become a plant? CO2 is better for them.

Comment: @H2CO3 ;-)  BTW you are an acid that destroys historical monuments when mixed with rain.